Assistance Needed: Updating Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business on an Offline Server
We have Windows Server 2019 with Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business.
Our server does not have Internet connectivity, and we need to update Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business to address several CVEs.
We have Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business version 2303 build 16.0.16130.20332 (March 20, 2023), and need to update to version 2401 build 16.0.17231.20236 (February 13, 2024) or the latest version.
I tried the Office Deployment Tool and Office Customization Tool to download the updates, but these tools only list Office Professional Plus 2019 and Office Standard 2019, with no option to download Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business.
Due to cybersecurity policies, we cannot connect any machines within the organization to the Internet. We need to download the latest Microsoft Office 2019 Home & Business updates on an online machine (outside the organization), transfer the update file to the server, and then install the updates.
Any alternative methods or specific troubleshooting steps to achieve this would be very helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019#retail-versions-of-office-2016-c2r-and-office-2019

Microsoft is very particular about how Office updates. It's best to stay within the rails. Also, Office 2019 only has one more year of updates... It's EOL in October 2025.

It would appear the Home & Business 2019 is supported by the ODT. You'll probably just need to use the correct Product ID in the XML configuration file. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/installation/product-ids-supported-office-deployment-click-to-run

Thank you for your valuable response. I used the methods outlined in the following links to update Office 2019 offline using the Office CDN method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ltsc/2021/deploy                                                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/installation/product-ids-supported-office-deployment-click-to-run
